Xamarin Forms WebView Error only on Android
[Android only]
Can anyone help? I have a Xamarin Forms (v5.0.0.2662) application with a webview in a submenue item. When I remove the webview the application works as excpected.
Steps for reproducing:

Navigate to view with webview
Navigate back (backwards navigation is always successfull)
Trying to navigate into any menue item (app crash with following exception)




Exception:
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1 in com.company.app:layout/shellcontent: Binary XML file line #1 in com.company.app:layout/shellcontent: Error inflating class <unknown> ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1 in com.company.app:layout/shellcontent: Error inflating class <unknown> ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 37: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x-------- a=7}
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00068] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11524 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00036] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:867 
  at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root) [0x0003a] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:671 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ShellContentFragment.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00019] in D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ShellContentFragment.cs:139 
  at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_inflater, System.IntPtr native_container, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00021] in C:\a\_work\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\monoandroid12.0\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:2031 
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L (_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0, System.IntPtr p1, System.IntPtr p2) [0x00005] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:352 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
  --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1 in com.company.app:layout/shellcontent: Binary XML file line #1 in com.company.app:layout/shellcontent: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1 in com.company.app:layout/shellcontent: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ShellContentFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ShellContentFragment.onCreateView(ShellContentFragment.java:71)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1817)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 37: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x-------- a=7}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:782)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5803)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:693)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:266)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:262)


AndroidManifest.xml
    <application android:label="lorem" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:allowBackup="false" android:largeHeap="true">

styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
   
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00a69e</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#00a69e</item>
        
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>

view with webview xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Class.xaml.cs"
             Shell.PresentationMode="Animated"
             Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             xmlns:converters1="clr-namespace:Application.Services.FormValidation.Converters;assembly=Application"
             xmlns:behaviours1="clr-namespace:Application.Services.FormValidation.Behaviours;assembly=Application"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Application.Custom;assembly=Application"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             Visual="Material"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <custom:KeyboardView>
        <WebView x:Name="WebView"></WebView>
    </custom:KeyboardView>
</ContentPage>

Class.xaml.cs:
...
...
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, string> query)
        {
            WebView.Source = "https://www.google.com";
            WebView.Navigated += WebViewOnNavigated;
            
            query.TryGetValue("navbar", out var value);
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                NavBarIsVisible = value == "true";
            }
            else
            {
                NavBarIsVisible = false;
            }

            query.TryGetValue("cameFrom", out var cameFrom);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cameFrom))
            {
                _cameFrom = cameFrom;
            }

            Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, NavBarIsVisible);
        }
...
...

Edit:
AppShell.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Application.Views"
       Title="Application"
       FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
       x:Class="Application.AppShellApplication">

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>

    <ShellItem Route="Application">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ApplicationPage}" />
    </ShellItem>

    <TabBar Route="MainPage">
        <Tab Title="Neue Fahrt" Icon="bus.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Meine Fahrten" Icon="history.png">
            <ShellContent Title="Trips" Icon="bus.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TripHistoryPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Einstellungen" Icon="einstellungen.png">
            <ShellContent Title="Trips" Icon="bus.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Kontakt" Icon="circle_info.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ContactPage}" />
        </Tab>

    </TabBar>

</Shell>

AppShellApplication.xaml.cs
using App.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class AppShellApplication : Shell
    {
        public AppShellApplication()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ItemDetailPage), typeof(ItemDetailPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NewItemPage), typeof(NewItemPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ConfirmRegistrationPage), typeof(ConfirmRegistrationPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LocationPermissionPage), typeof(LocationPermissionPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(RegisterPage), typeof(RegisterPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(CreditcardPage), typeof(CreditcardPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AdditionalPassengerPage), typeof(AdditionalPassengerPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UserProfilePage), typeof(UserProfilePage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(CreditcardEditPage), typeof(CreditcardEditPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LogPage), typeof(LogPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ResetPasswordPage), typeof(ResetPasswordPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ConfirmResetPasswordPage), typeof(ConfirmResetPasswordPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TripOverviewPage), typeof(TripOverviewPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ChangePasswordPage), typeof(ChangePasswordPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ResetMobileNrPage), typeof(ResetMobileNrPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ConfirmResetMobileNrPage), typeof(ConfirmResetMobileNrPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ChangeMailPage), typeof(ChangeMailPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ConfirmResetMailPage), typeof(ConfirmResetMailPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ContactPage), typeof(ContactPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ContactFormPage), typeof(ContactFormPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(FAQPage), typeof(FAQPage));
        }
    }
}


I have a Xamarin Forms (v5.0.0.2662) application with a webview in a submenue item What's the submenu item? Is it a Shell Tab?

Could you also include the relevant code for custom:KeyboardView to help us  reproduce?

@LiqunShen-MSFT yes it's a Shell Tab - the custom:KeyboardView can be ignored, I already tried to remove the KeyboardView and the application behaved the same way

So, the WebView Page is also contained in a Shell Tab, right? And for the reproducing steps, when navigating to the WebView Page, it works. But when navigating to other tabs, it crashes?

Could you share the code for AppShell.xaml and AppShell.xaml.cs?

@LiqunShen-MSFT I added some pictures of the application menue, I hope it helps - the AppShell.xml and AppShell.xaml.cs has been added too.

Is the Kreditkarte hinzufugen the WebView page? What's the route for this page?

And could you elaborate more on how to reproduce this issue?

@LiqunShen-MSFT yes the "Kreditkarte hinzufugen" is the WebView page - the navigation to the page happens with:
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("CreditcardPage?navbar=true&cameFrom=edit");
The navigation to the webview happens by a Frame onClick and always by Shell.Current.GoToAsync(...);

Have you tried setting a breakpoint to figure out which line cause the error?
